# Molecule export to PDB fails in WL but succeeds in rdkit

Tags: export, chemistry

The following is one of a whole list of molecules which Mathematica fails to export to PDB:

```
ClearAll[mol];
mol = Molecule[
    "CC1=CC(C2=CC(CC(=O)C3=CC=C(C)C(CC4=NC=CC(C5=CC=CN=C5)=N4)=C3)=CC(C(F)(F)F)=C2)C=C1",
    IncludeHydrogens -> True
];

ExportString[mol, {"PDB", "Molecule"}]
(* $Failed *)
```

But `rdkit` manages to export it correctly:

```
Python 3.8.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 25 2021, 22:54:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> from rdkit import Chem
>>> from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
>>> mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("CC1=CC(C2=CC(CC(=O)C3=CC=C(C)C(CC4=NC=CC(C5=CC=CN=C5)=N4)=C3)=CC(C(F)(F)F)=C2)C=C1")
>>> fp = os.path.join("path", "to", "mol.pdb")
>>> AllChem.rdmolfiles.MolToPDBFile(mol, fp)
>>>
```

And I can confirm by inspecting the file that the molecule has been exported correctly.

Any idea what might be going on? Am I missing a specific option in WL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ExportString[Molecule["CC1=CC(C2=CC(CC(=O)C3=CC=C(C)C(CC4=NC=CC(C5=CC=CN=C5)=N4)=C3)=CC(C(F)(F)F)=C2)C=C1", IncludeHydrogens -> True], "PDB"]` seems to work OK.

Comment: @J.M. you are correct! But this is so strange. I have the `Molecule` already, which won't export, but will when I do `Molecule[MoleculeValue[mol, "CanonicalSMILES"], IncludeHydrogens -> All]`.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui I will accept your comment as an answer if you post it. The solution is working for me.

Comment: I also don't reproduce the result from the WL code here, I get a PDB file string just fine.  If you have a particular `Molecule` expression that doesn't export to PDB, you can file a [bug report](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback) and attach a notebook with the problem molecule.

Comment: In MMA 12.0 (Win10-64) the export command fails with a clearly bug-smelling "Export::type: RuleDelayed cannot be exported to the PDB format.". This looks like something went wrong inside. However, the same code works fine on MMA 12.2 (cloud version). I assume WRI fixed whatever bug they had in their internal code.